# Theia integration into existing electron app - Can't find drivelist.node native module

Tags: webpack, electron, theia

I'm trying to integrate Theia editor directly into an existing Electron app for nearly a week without success. All the Electron examples show running Theia standalone but not how to integrate it into an existing Electron app.

`theia build` command generates a `lib` folder with a full blown Theia app. I don't think this is what I need.

My existing `BrowserWindow` has `contextIsolation` enabled and there is a PR in Theia to [Enable contextIsolation](https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia/pull/12299) which is on the verge of being merged to master.

Assuming this will get merged any day now, I think what I need is to ignore `@theia/electron` and instead have my electron main process start up a Theia `BackendApplication` intended for the browser (from `@theia/core/lib/node/backend-application-module`).

My front end app can then communicate with that server as it would from the browser, since my BrowserWindow does not have access to Node runtime anyways (due to contextIsolation).

Assuming this is the correct path for me, I'm running into issues reconciling the location of compiled native modules. When adding the following minimal code from Theia into my Electron main.ts:

```
require('reflect-metadata');
const { Container } = require('inversify')
const { backendApplicationModule } = require('@theia/core/lib/node/backend-application-module');
const container = new Container();
container.load(backendApplicationModule);
```

I get the following error when running my app:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
→ /Users/admin/code/client/app/build/drivelist.node
→ /Users/admin/code/client/app/build/Debug/drivelist.node
→ /Users/admin/code/client/app/build/Release/drivelist.node
→ /Users/admin/code/client/app/out/Debug/drivelist.node
→ /Users/admin/code/client/app/Debug/drivelist.node
→ /Users/admin/code/client/app/out/Release/drivelist.node
→ /Users/admin/code/client/app/Release/drivelist.node
→ /Users/admin/code/client/app/build/default/drivelist.node
```

My Electron app compiles native modules using `electron-builder install-app-deps`

I understand that Theia also needs to compile some native modules for the browser or for electron.

`theia rebuild:browser`

gives me

`native node modules are already rebuilt for browser`

I don't see where they got compiled, but Ok..

`theia rebuild:browser && theia rebuild:electron`

gives me a new `.brower_modules` folder with the needed **drivelist.node** module:

[image]

However, clearly when the app loads it is not checking that location and is not finding `driverlist.node`

My Electron app gets compiled with webpack and has a relevant `node-loader`:

```
{
     test: /.node$/,
     loader: 'node-loader',
}
```

This works to load the native modules my Electron app needs. However, once I add the Theia code it can't find the `driverlist.node` which is clearly in my sight in `.browser_modules`.

I've tried various configurations for this node-loader, among other things, and can't figure it out.

Comment: Please add a link from where you got this code `require('reflect-metadata')...` Of course, I would like a minimally reproducible project (not to miss the details), but I don't know if you can provide it.I'm not sure if this will help, since there is no way to check, but have you tried `import { Container } from '@theia/core/shared/inversify';` maybe it's a different library, but I see it on github

Comment: Have you tried without `node-loader`? We personally use no node loader and our Electron app works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I remember I had used electron-rebuild package to rebuild native modules for my Electron app.

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

Also before that, to make sure the native module path is correct, console.log statements can be used to check if the correct path is set and if the module being loaded is not undefined.

ALso native module's versions sometimes mismatch. like, Theia and electron version compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the path to the **.browser_modules** folder to the **NODE_PATH** env ver in your Electron app main process

```
    process.env.NODE_PATH = `${__dirname}/.browser_modules`;
    require('module').Module._initPaths();
...code
```

Comment: I wil try this in the next couple of days. I'm hopeful and if it works I'll reward additional bounty as mine expired before I can test. If you have anything to add before then, feel free. thanks